# What the difference between these two examples with infinitive and gerund?

Tags: present-perfect, gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive

1) He has just finished **writing**

2) He has just finished **to write**

Comment: The principal difference is that one is grammatical, the other is not: *finish* does not take infinitival complements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are trying to understand the differences between gerund and infinitive after certain verbs. Unfortunately, after "finish" verb, we just have gerund only.

F.Y.I: we just have some verbs having both forms (gerund and infinitive) with different meaning, not all verbs having that "feature"